# How do I convert a Joda Time DateTime object into a String in SQL Server format?

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, jodatime

I am using the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library in Java, and have a date and time stored as an [org.joda.time.DateTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) object.

How can I reliably convert this DateTime object into a String that will be parsed correctly by SQL server (including timezone), such that I can use it in an INSERT SQL statement?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`java.sql.Timestamp`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) with [`PreparedStatement#setTimestamp()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setTimestamp%28int,%20java.sql.Timestamp%29).

```
ps.setTimestamp(1, new Timestamp(dateTime.getMillis()));
```

Note that [`java.sql.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) stores only the date part, not the time part.

Answer (score 43):

you can try this simple code :

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime();
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String dtStr = fmt.print(dt);
```

Answer (score 7):

Be careful to consider time zones. Using new Timestamp() may be tricky since it expects time in milliseconds in GMT.

```
    DateTime dt = new DateTime(2010, 1, 1, 14, 30, 59, 1, DateTimeZone.forOffsetHoursMinutes(7, 0));
    Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(dt.getMillis());
    System.out.println(dt); // prints 2010-01-01T14:30:59.001+07:00
    System.out.println(ts); // prints 2010-01-01 08:30:59.001

    DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    String sqlTimeString = fmt.print(dt);
    System.out.println(sqlTimeString); // prints 2010-01-01 14:30:59
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Simply Function

I use this simple function to get a SQL-friendly date format from a **JodaTime** `DateTime` object:

```
// Converts a DateTime object into a SQL-format friendly string.
//
// Return format looks like this: 2014-01-22 10:05:34.546
//
public static String toSql(DateTime dateTime) {
    return new Timestamp( dateTime.getMillis() ).toString();
}
```