# Joda-Time: convert SimpleDateFormat pattern to DateTimeFormat.forPattern

Tags: java, jodatime, thread-local, sql-timestamp

I'm trying to modify some code to use `Joda-Time` rather than `java.sql.Timestamp`

Currently the code is using `Threadlocal` and SimpleDateFormat:

```
 public static final ThreadLocal<DateFormat> FORMAT_TIMESTAMP = new ThreadLocal<DateFormat>() {
    @Override
    protected DateFormat initialValue() {
        return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX");
    }
};

public static String format(Timestamp timestamp) {
    return FORMAT_TIMESTAMP.get().format(timestamp);
}
```

My understanding is that Joda-time is thread safe, so there is no need to use `ThreadLocal`

With this in mind I have modified the code to this:

```
 public static String format(Instant timestamp) {

    Instant formated = Instant.parse(timestamp.toString(), DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX"));

    return formated.toString();
}
```

If I nned to insert the values into a DB later in the code I plan to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3780120/how-do-i-convert-a-joda-time-datetime-object-into-a-string-in-sql-server-format) method.

Assuming I'm going about this the right way, is there anyway to format the `DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX")` like the

`SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX")`

At the moment I'm getting a `Invalid format` Exception

Comment: I don't understand. In your first example, you are `format`ting a `Timestamp`. In your second example you are attempting to parse the `String` created by `Timestamp#toString` into an `Instant` instance and then return the `Instant#toString` result (which might be different from your `DateTimeFormat`'s format. `DateTimeFormat` does not have a `X` pattern character. Just use `DateTimeFormat#print(timestamp.getTime())`. I didn't notice `timestamp` was a `Instant` in your second example. What happened to `Timestamp`?

Comment: Sorry that was a silly mistake on my part

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`X` is not recognised by Joda. Replacing the `XXX` by `ZZ` should do what you need.

Because `DateTimeFormat` is thread safe, you can share it across threads. So your code could look like this:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter FORMAT_TIMESTAMP =
                                      DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZ");

public static String format(Instant timestamp) {
    return FORMAT_TIMESTAMP.print(timestamp);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

- No need to define the formatting pattern for standard inputs.
- Parse directly into java.time objects.

Examples…

```
// offset-from-UTC
OffsetDateTime.parse( "2016-01-23T12:34:56.123456789-07:00" )
```

…

```
// Z = Zulu = UTC
Instant.parse( "2016-01-23T12:34:56.123456789Z" )
```

…

```
// ISO 8601 format extended with time zone name appended in square brackets.
ZonedDateTime.parse( "2016-01-23T12:34:56.123456789-05:30[Asia/Kolkata]" )
```

## Details

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

## java.time

No need for `ThreadLocal` as the java.time classes are inherently [thread-safe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety) because of they are [immutable objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object).

The standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats for date-time values are used by default in the java.time classes. So generally no need to specify a formatting pattern for such inputs.

### `Instant`

The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

The [`Instant.parse`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-) method can parse standard input strings ending in `Z`, short for `Zulu`, meaning [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( 
    "2016-01-23T12:34:56.123456789Z" );
```

## `OffsetDateTime`

For standard input strings that include a specific [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset), use the [`OffsetDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) class and its [`parse`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-) method.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( 
    "2016-01-23T12:34:56.123456789-07:00" );
```

## `ZonedDateTime`

The `ZonedDateTime` class with its `toString` method generates a String in a format that extends beyond the ISO 8601 format by appending the name in square brackets. This is wise, as a [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) is much more than an [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset). A time zone is an offset *plus* a set of rules for handling anomalies such as [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time).

This class can parse as well as generate such strings.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse( 
    "2016-01-23T12:34:56.123456789-05:30[Asia/Kolkata]" ) ;
```

### `DateTimeFormatter`

For non-standard string formats, search Stack Overflow for [`java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class.

### Database

To send this value to a database through a JDBC driver supporting JDBC 4.2 or later, use the `PreparedStatement::setObject` method and for fetching, the `ResultSet::getObject` method.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , instant );
```

If your driver does not comply, fall back to converting to the old java.sql types. Look to the [new conversion methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#from-java.time.Instant-) added to the old classes.

```
java.sql.Timestamp ts = java.sql.Timestamp.from( instant );
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [*ThreeTenABP*](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts ***ThreeTen-Backport*** (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).